# url to post on the facebook application for android

Tags: android, facebook, http

it is possible to use a url to post directly on the facebook application, I know that twitter uses :

> "twitter://post?message=MessageTest"

Facebook for iOS uses:

> "fb://publish/?text=MessageTest"

Does anyone know how to find the url to post on the facebook application for android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need to use [FACEBOOK SDK FOR ANDROID](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)
and for applying this plugin and to post on fb wall have a look at [Adding Facebook integration to an Android application](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/) 
this tutorial

Comment: Thank you, I will test this solution, but having to integrate the facebook sdk is heavy as a solution, are you sure there are no other solutions like those of twitter or facebook on IOS?
I stay on topic in hoping better :).

Comment: i don't think there is any other solution...facebook sdk has been provided by facebook only.so there are lots of task we need to do when we are using facebook to our mobile application like:posting msg,posting video,fetching friendlist,friend's birthdate etc...all thing are done with the help of this sdk.so this sdk is so much helpful,u need to register your apps for facebook at facebook developer site...for more detail see tutorial of that blog link i have given....